# How can I change folder color of Mac Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, oh-my-zsh

I want to change the color of the text background. I tried to change the code of `vi .oh-my-zsh/themes/cloud.zsh-theme` file. But I don't know how to do.

```
# .oh-my-zsh/themes/cloud.zsh-theme
if [[ -z $ZSH_THEME_CLOUD_PREFIX ]]; then
    ZSH_THEME_CLOUD_PREFIX=''
fi

if [[ "$USERNAME" != "$DEFAULT_USER" || -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]]; then
    ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_USER="$USERNAME"
fi

PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}$ZSH_THEME_CLOUD_PREFIX %{$fg_bold[green]%}$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_USER %{$fg_bold[cyan]%} %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[green]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[blue]%} % %{$reset_color%}'

ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[green]%}[%{$fg[cyan]%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX="%{$reset_color%}"
#ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_DIRTY="%{$fg[green]%}] %{$fg[yellow]%}⚡ %{$reset_color%}"
ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_CLEAN="%{$fg[green]%}]"
```

I want to change the color of the text background. It's currently yellow, but what should I do if I want to change it so that there's not colored?
Also, I want to change the letters(for folders) in blue to white. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Maybe: [How do I uninstall Oh My Zsh?](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-oh-my-zsh).  ?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the PROMPT line to remove the background color and change the folder letters to white. Replace the line with the following code:

```
PROMPT='%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}$ZSH_THEME_CLOUD_PREFIX %{$fg_bold[green]%}$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_USER %{$fg_bold[cyan]%} %{$fg[cyan]%}%c %{$fg_bold[green]%}$(git_prompt_info)%{$fg_bold[white]%} % '
```

In the modified code, the `%{$reset_color%}` part is removed to remove the background color, and `%{$fg_bold[blue]%}` is changed to `%{$fg_bold[white]%}` to make the folder letters white.

```
Save the changes and exit the text editor. In the vi editor, you can press the Esc key and then type `:wq` to save and exit.
```

After making these changes, the text background color should be removed, and the folder letters will appear in white. Remember to reload your terminal or open a new terminal window to see the changes take effect.

Comment: I changed to that code, but it still doesn't work.